# i am using odoo 12 and trying to click on Delivery inside sales order and give me this error

Tags: python

Error:
Odoo Server Error

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 656, in _handle_exception
return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 314, in _handle_exception
raise pycompat.reraise(type(exception), exception, sys.exc_info()[2])
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\tools\pycompat.py", line 87, in reraise
raise value
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 698, in dispatch
result = self._call_function(**self.params)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 346, in _call_function
return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\service\model.py", line 98, in wrapper
return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 339, in checked_call
result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 941, in **call**
return self.method(*args, **kw)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 519, in response_wrap
response = f(*args, **kw)
File "c:\program files (x86)\odoo 12.0\server\odoo\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 962, in call_kw
return self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
File "c:\program files (x86)\odoo 12.0\server\odoo\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 954, in _call_kw
return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\api.py", line 755, in call_kw
return _call_kw_model(method, model, args, kwargs)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\api.py", line 728, in _call_kw_model
result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\models.py", line 1396, in load_views
for [v_id, v_type] in views
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\models.py", line 1396, in 
for [v_id, v_type] in views
File "c:\program files (x86)\odoo 12.0\server\odoo\addons\mail\models\mail_thread.py", line 409, in fields_view_get
res = super(MailThread, self).fields_view_get(view_id=view_id, view_type=view_type, toolbar=toolbar, submenu=submenu)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\models.py", line 1482, in fields_view_get
xarch, xfields = View.postprocess_and_fields(self._name, etree.fromstring(result['arch']), view_id)
File "c:\program files (x86)\odoo 12.0\server\odoo\addons\crnd_web_diagram_plus\models\ir_ui_view.py", line 25, in postprocess_and_fields
model, node, view_id)
File "c:\program files (x86)\odoo 12.0\server\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_ui_view.py", line 1131, in postprocess_and_fields
self.raise_view_error(message, view_id)
File "c:\program files (x86)\odoo 12.0\server\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_ui_view.py", line 568, in raise_view_error
raise ValueError(message)
ValueError: Field `website_id` does not exist

Error context:
View `stock.picking.form`
[view_id: 1082, xml_id: stock.view_picking_form, model: stock.picking, parent_id: n/a]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: you know after creating quotation then confirm it to sales order. a button with delivery name will appear after confirmation. when i want to click on delivery button give me this error.